# Discord.py bot, can I do a heavy task "off to the side" so I don't lag inputs?

Tags: python, python-3.x, web-scraping, async-await, python-asyncio

I have a Discord bot in Python / Discord.py where people can enter commands, and normally the bot responds very quickly.

However the bot is also gathering/scraping webdata every iteration of the main loop. Normally the scraping is pretty short and sweet so nobody really notices, but from time to time the code is set up to do a more thorough scraping which takes a lot more time. But during these heavy scrapings, the bot is sort of unresponsive to user commands.

```
@bot.command()
async def sample_command(ctx):
    # may actually take a while for this command to respond if we happen to be
    # in the middle of a heavier site scrape
    await ctx.channel.send("Random message, something indicating bot has responded")  

async def main_loop():
    sem = asyncio.Semaphore(60)
    connector = aiohttp.TCPConnector(limit=60)

    async with aiohttp.ClientSession(connector=connector, headers=headers) as session:
        while True:
            # main guts of loop here ... 

            scrapers = [scraper_1(session, sem), scraper_2(session, sem), ...]
            data = list(chain(*await asyncio.gather(*scrapers)))  # this may take a while

            # do stuff with data
```

Is there a way to sort of have it go "Hey, you want to do a heavy scrape, fine go process it elsewhere - meanwhile let's continue with the main loop and I'll hook back up with you later when you're done and we'll process the data then", if that makes sense?

I mainly want to separate this scraping step so it's not holding up the ability for people to actually interact with the rest of the bot.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can use `asyncio.create_task()` to spawn the scraping in the "background":

```
async def scrape_and_process(...):
    scrapers = [scraper_1(session, sem), scraper_2(session, sem), ...]
    data = list(chain(*await asyncio.gather(*scrapers)))  # this may take a while
    # do stuff with data

async def main_loop():
    sem = asyncio.Semaphore(60)
    connector = aiohttp.TCPConnector(limit=60)

    async with aiohttp.ClientSession(connector=connector, headers=headers) as session:
        while True:
            # main guts of loop here ... 

            # initiate scraping and processing in the background and
            # proceed with the loop
            asyncio.create_task(scrape_and_process(...))
```

Answer (score 1):

**You can use the discord.py tasks extension [docs](https://discordpy.readthedocs.io/en/latest/ext/tasks/index.html).**

**For example:**

```py
from discord.ext import tasks

@bot.event()
async def on_ready():
    main_loop.start()

@bot.command()
async def sample_command(ctx):
    await ctx.channel.send("Random message, something indicating bot has responded")  

@tasks.loop(seconds=60)
async def main_loop():
    do_something()
```

Note: It's not recommended to start the tasks in on_ready because the bot will reconnect to discord and the task will start several times, Put it somewhere else or on_ready check if this the first connect.

Another simple tip: you can use `await ctx.send()` instead of `await ctx.channel.send()`

Answer (score 0):

You can try to use python threading.

Learn more [here](https://docs.python.org/3/library/threading.html)

It basically allows you to run it on different threads

example:

```py
import threading

def 1():
  print("Helo! This is the first thread")

def 2():
  print("Bonjour! This is the second thread")

thread1 = threading.Thread(target=1)
thread2 = Threading.Thread(target=2)

thread1.start()
thread2.start()
```

Comment: Threading is probably not the way to go here because the OP wants to run code that involves asyncio in the background, and asyncio is single-threaded. Also, asyncio is capable of doing multiple things concurrently - that is its core functionality.